How to calculate windows in snowflake dataset?
Database is Snowflake. 
I have a dataset of cases created by customers and there are agents assigned to these cases.  how_to_get_agent_72hr column is what I am trying to figure out. I have added this column to show expected output. The requirement is that any case created within the 72 hours should be assigned to agent from the previous case. Important note: Notice that case 15 is within 72 hours case 14 but it's not assigned to Alejandro because window for Alejandro started at 2024-04-05 17:47:00 and would end at 2024-04-08 17:47:00. So 72 hours is calculate from the time the window started.



customer_id
case_id
case_dt
agent
how_to_get_agent_72hr
Notes




1
case_1
2020-11-10 16:52:22
Sean
Sean



1
case_2
2020-11-25 17:50:55
Alico
Alico



1
case_3
2022-07-27 17:54:34
Katherine
Katherine



1
case_4
2022-10-05 11:36:43
Victor
Victor



1
case_5
2022-10-18 23:11:03
Automated
Automated
window1 starts here


1
case_6
2022-10-19 8:44:58
Denzel
Automated



1
case_7
2022-10-20 17:13:00
Salesforce
Automated



1
case_8
2022-10-20 17:15:44
Salesforce
Automated
ends


1
case_9
2023-02-24 12:32:16
Aryll
Aryll



1
case_10
2023-11-02 17:29:04
Kristine
Kristine



1
case_11
2023-12-23 16:34:00
Katherine
Katherine



1
case_12
2024-04-05 17:47:00
Alejandro
Alejandro
window2 starts here


1
case_13
2024-04-06 21:49:11
Angel
Alejandro



1
case_14
2024-04-08 8:16:51
Wilbert
Alejandro
ends


1
case_15
2024-04-09 16:34:27
Ezekiel
Ezekiel
window3 starts here


1
case_16
2024-04-09 17:16:27
Renz
Ezekiel



1
case_17
2024-04-10 17:59:06
Raymond
Ezekiel



1
case_18
2024-04-11 22:35:56
Glen
Ezekiel
end


1
case_19
2024-04-15 13:37:32
Rashid
Rashid





given you want to carry state across rows, you should use a user defined table function to carry the rolling window of start,user

@SimeonPilgrim Can you elaborate bit more - how would udtf solve this? What would be the input and what would be the output?

given you want to carry state, you need something that can carry state. Tablualr Javascript UDF's solve this given they can hold state. So you will need to use one of those (or the python style, or use a Java function)

Tabular JavaScript UDFs (UDTFs)
create or replace function carry_func(epoch float, name string) 
returns table(carry_name string)
language javascript as
'{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.last_epoch = 0.0;
        this.last_name = "";
    },
    processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
        var diff = row.EPOCH - this.last_epoch;
        if(diff > 259200.0 /*72*60*60*/) {
            this.last_epoch = row.EPOCH;
            this.last_name = row.NAME;
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({CARRY_NAME: this.last_name});
    }
}';

over your data:
with data(customer_id, case_id, case_dt, agent, how_to_get_agent_72hr, Notes) as (
    select * from values
  (1, 'case_1' , '2020-11-10 16:52:22'::timestamp, 'Sean', 'Sean', ''),
  (1, 'case_2' , '2020-11-25 17:50:55'::timestamp, 'Alico', 'Alico', ''),
  (1, 'case_3' , '2022-07-27 17:54:34'::timestamp, 'Katherine', 'Katherine', ''),
  (1, 'case_4' , '2022-10-05 11:36:43'::timestamp, 'Victor', 'Victor', ''),
  (1, 'case_5' , '2022-10-18 23:11:03'::timestamp, 'Automated', 'Automated', 'window1 starts here'),
  (1, 'case_6' , '2022-10-19 08:44:58'::timestamp, 'Denzel', 'Automated', ''),
  (1, 'case_7' , '2022-10-20 17:13:00'::timestamp, 'Salesforce', 'Automated', ''),
  (1, 'case_8' , '2022-10-20 17:15:44'::timestamp, 'Salesforce', 'Automated', 'ends'),
  (1, 'case_9' , '2023-02-24 12:32:16'::timestamp, 'Aryll', 'Aryll', ''),
  (1, 'case_10', '2023-11-02 17:29:04'::timestamp, 'Kristine', 'Kristine', ''),
  (1, 'case_11', '2023-12-23 16:34:00'::timestamp, 'Katherine', 'Katherine', ''),
  (1, 'case_12', '2024-04-05 17:47:00'::timestamp, 'Alejandro', 'Alejandro', 'window2 starts here'),
  (1, 'case_13', '2024-04-06 21:49:11'::timestamp, 'Angel', 'Alejandro', ''),
  (1, 'case_14', '2024-04-08 08:16:51'::timestamp, 'Wilbert', 'Alejandro', 'ends'),
  (1, 'case_15', '2024-04-09 16:34:27'::timestamp, 'Ezekiel', 'Ezekiel', 'window3 starts here'),
  (1, 'case_16', '2024-04-09 17:16:27'::timestamp, 'Renz', 'Ezekiel', ''),
  (1, 'case_17', '2024-04-10 17:59:06'::timestamp, 'Raymond', 'Ezekiel', ''),
  (1, 'case_18', '2024-04-11 22:35:56'::timestamp, 'Glen', 'Ezekiel', 'end'),
  (1, 'case_19', '2024-04-15 13:37:32'::timestamp, 'Rashid', 'Rashid', '')
)
select *
from data as d,
 table(carry_func(DATE_PART(epoch_second,d.case_dt)::float, d.agent) 
      over (partition by d.customer_id order by d.case_dt))

make sure to use the OVER clause to partition and order those rows, or your results are random..



CUSTOMER_ID
CASE_ID
CASE_DT
AGENT
HOW_TO_GET_AGENT_72HR
NOTES
CARRY_NAME




1
case_1
2020-11-10 16:52:22.000
Sean
Sean

Sean


1
case_2
2020-11-25 17:50:55.000
Alico
Alico

Alico


1
case_3
2022-07-27 17:54:34.000
Katherine
Katherine

Katherine


1
case_4
2022-10-05 11:36:43.000
Victor
Victor

Victor


1
case_5
2022-10-18 23:11:03.000
Automated
Automated
window1 starts here
Automated


1
case_6
2022-10-19 08:44:58.000
Denzel
Automated

Automated


1
case_7
2022-10-20 17:13:00.000
Salesforce
Automated

Automated


1
case_8
2022-10-20 17:15:44.000
Salesforce
Automated
ends
Automated


1
case_9
2023-02-24 12:32:16.000
Aryll
Aryll

Aryll


1
case_10
2023-11-02 17:29:04.000
Kristine
Kristine

Kristine


1
case_11
2023-12-23 16:34:00.000
Katherine
Katherine

Katherine


1
case_12
2024-04-05 17:47:00.000
Alejandro
Alejandro
window2 starts here
Alejandro


1
case_13
2024-04-06 21:49:11.000
Angel
Alejandro

Alejandro


1
case_14
2024-04-08 08:16:51.000
Wilbert
Alejandro
ends
Alejandro


1
case_15
2024-04-09 16:34:27.000
Ezekiel
Ezekiel
window3 starts here
Ezekiel


1
case_16
2024-04-09 17:16:27.000
Renz
Ezekiel

Ezekiel


1
case_17
2024-04-10 17:59:06.000
Raymond
Ezekiel

Ezekiel


1
case_18
2024-04-11 22:35:56.000
Glen
Ezekiel
end
Ezekiel


1
case_19
2024-04-15 13:37:32.000
Rashid
Rashid

Rashid




Awesome! I am going to try this on some of my my edge cases. Do you know if this can be used in dbt? I have never created UDTF using dbt.

I have never used dbt, so do not know, I would assume it all possible, but that just an assumption.

I am running into an issue converting the javascript udtf into python udtf. Could you please help with that?

why would you change it?

It is just for my learning. I wanted to see if this can be accomplished using python also. The code you provided works perfectly.

That is a great reason. No I will not help (at this point of time). Good luck though.
